# Knockout Updating ViewModel Radiobox change

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

Scenario.
I have a radio list of lookup objects from the database. When a different radio button is selected, I need to update the text on the screen.  I have managed to update the value but I can't manage to update the display. What would be the best method to do this?

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CassiusKillay/P42fA/

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: workExperienceLookupList">
<li> 
    <input data-bind="attr: {value: Id}, checked: $root.WorkExperienceType.Id" type="radio" name="WorkExperienceType" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: Description"> </span>
</li>
</div>   
<span data-bind="text: WorkExperienceType.Id"></span>
<span data-bind="text: WorkExperienceType.Description"></span>
```

Script:

```
function ViewModel() {
this.WorkExperienceType = new Lookup(initialLookup); //From database
this.workExperienceLookupList = lookupList; //From database
}

function Lookup(data) {
this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
this.EnDescription = data.EnDescription;
this.CyDescription = data.CyDescription;
this.IsActive = data.IsActive;
this.SortOrder = data.SortOrder;
}

var lookupList = [{
"Id": 1,
"Description": "Description 1"
}, {
"Id": 2,
"Description": "Description 2"
}, {
"Id": 3,
"Description": "Description 3"
}, {
"Id": 4,
"Description": "Description 4"
}];

var initialLookup = {
"Id": 3,
"Description": "Description 3",
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a Select can be bound to an object in the way you're looking for, see [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044189/can-a-knockout-observable-be-data-bound-to-the-value-of-a-radio-button). However, you can accomplish what you're looking in at least two ways, the way described in detail below, or with a custom binding.

What I did was:

- Changed `WorkExperienceType` to an observable and updated view accordingly
- Updated view to reference new `SelectedWorkExperienceType` observable which stores the selected work type's Id.
- Added a subscription to `SelectedWorkExperienceType` such that when a new value is selected, we search for the appropriate value in the list and set the `WorkExperienceType` accordingly.

The main changes were in the ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.WorkExperienceType = ko.observable(new Lookup(initialLookup)); //From database
self.workExperienceLookupList = lookupList; //From database
self.SelectedWorkExperienceType = ko.observable();
self.SelectedWorkExperienceType.subscribe(function (newVal) {
    var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.workExperienceLookupList, function(item) { 
        return item.Id == newVal; 
    });

    self.WorkExperienceType(item);
});
```

}

I've modified your fiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/P42fA/22/