# Get javascript object from radio element in knockout foreach loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is my HTML code:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: complimentaryCustomerList">
    <label><span data-bind="text: ($data.Surname + ', ' + $data.GivenName)"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="companion" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.complimentaryCustomerSelection" /> 
    </label>
</span>
```

My problem is `self.complimentaryCustomerSelection()` shows as "[object object]", an actual string. Is there a way to pass an object from the array?

Comment: I don't understand. The `checked` binding can have an observable bound to it, so in case the `complimentaryCustomerSelection` is a plain object you should wrap it? Could you provide the JavaScript view model that belongs to this snippet?

Comment: The view model is huge, but for simplicity, it contains two objects, one of which has a property that is an array that I'm looping through here.

The object that I am passing is not an observable though, it's a regular javascript object.

Comment: Then that's your problem. I really can't say more without some relative code? Couldn't you dumb the example down and put in a Fiddle or on Plunkr?

Comment: Can I wrap the data object in a knockout variable so it gets set properly?

Comment: Correction, is there a way to wrap it in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want the functionality of the `checkedValue` binding/handler available with checkboxes for radio-buttons. Sadly, radio-buttons aren't as simple and require some special considerations as seen in the two examples available within [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044189/can-a-knockout-observable-be-data-bound-to-the-value-of-a-radio-button)

Instead of using `.grep`, as in those examples, an alternative would be to use `JSON.parse` and `ko.toJSON` to serialize the object between JS and JSON([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/dvdM8/)).

```
 <input type="radio" name="companion" data-bind="value: function(){return ko.toJSON($data)}(), checked: $parent.complimentaryJSONHolder "/> 


 vm.complimentaryJSONHolder.subscribe(function(nv){
   vm.complimentaryJSHolder(JSON.parse(nv))
 })
```

---

Either solution will "work" but it ultimately sounds like you may be better off using a combobox/select, as they have better support/bindings for objects.

**Note**: Replace the external resource for knockout on the other two fiddles with http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js